# prediction error measures for Poisson regression in rpart

Tags: cross-validation, poisson-regression, measurement-error, rpart

My question is about an alternative prediction error measure besides the default deviance-based error that is implemented but not documented.

The [vignette (section 8.1)](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rpart/vignettes/longintro.pdf) states that:

> Prediction error:  The deviance contribution for a new observation, using $\hat{\lambda}$ of the node as the predicted rate.

Examining the [source code (poissonpred function)](https://github.com/cran/rpart/blob/master/src/poisson.c) I actually found two implemented measures: the deviance-based one, and a square root based one:
$$err = \left(\sqrt{c_{obs}}-\sqrt{\hat{\lambda}t_{obs}}\right)^2$$
where $c_{obs}$ is the event count for the new observation, $t_{obs}$ is the new observation time, and $\hat{\lambda}$ is the predicted rate.
The code only mentions

> A version based on square roots, which is the variance stabilizing transform

It can be used by specifying `rpart(...,method="poisson",...,parms=list(...,method="sqrt"))` (default is `method="deviance"`) and it solves the problem raised by the use of the deviance-based prediction error during the cross-validation procedure (see section 8.2 in the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rpart/vignettes/longintro.pdf)) but I wasn't able to find any reference nor justification for this square root based prediction error metric.

Does anyone know a reference or justification for the use of this metric?